# StackOverflow error on instantiation

Tags: c#, stack-overflow, instantiation

I'm getting a StackOverflow error whenever I instantiate this class in C#.
Can anyone explain why?

```
class Money
{
    public Money(decimal value, Currency usedCurrency)
    {
        Value = value;
        UsedCurrency = usedCurrency;
    }

    public decimal Value
    {
        get { return Value; }
        set { Value = Math.Round(value, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven); }
    }

    public Currency UsedCurrency;
}

public enum Currency
{
    USD,
    EUR,
    GBP,
    CAD,
    AUD
}
```

Here is an instantiation example :

```
var money = new Money(100, Currency.USD);
```

Answer (score 14):

Your property is referencing itself. When you try to get `Value`, it refers to `Value`... which tries to get `Value` again... and on and on.

```
public decimal Value
{
    get { return Value; }
    set { Value = Math.Round(value, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven); }
}
```

Use a backing field. *(Also, I'd rename your property to something more meaningful, especially since `value` has a special meaning.)*

```
private decimal roundedCurrency;
public decimal RoundedCurrency
{
    get { return roundedCurrency; }
    set { roundedCurrency = Math.Round(value, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven); }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need a backing field for your property `Value`. In your current code, `get/set` for the property are trying to set the property, thus introducing recursive calls and `Stackoverflow` exception.

```
private decimal _Value;

public decimal Value
{
    get { return _Value; }
    set { _Value = Math.Round(value, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven); }
}
```